# RDD Creation in PYspark

Tags: pyspark

Everything in Spark is created in the form of RDD (Key and value pairs). Is this necessary? Which type of analytics can be created/performed through an RDD dataset?
Please provide an example and uses of converting it to an RDD

Thanks,
Aditya

Answer (score 0):

Spark is used to solve problems which involve huge datasets where data transformation is required, Spark is built with functional programming language (Scala) instead than imperative language (C or C++) since functional programming allows to separate tasks in a lazy way between multiple nodes in a cluster which imperative programming paradigms cannot do and depend on an external data store for distributed algorithms to work. In Spark there are many libraries that perform distributed machine learning algorithms, which is something impossible with standard R or Python scripts